# how to use vertical scroll in react material top tab navigation

Tags: react-native, scrollbar, react-native-navigation

[Expected behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVEGT.jpg)
[Expected behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/832sF.jpg)

I want to use material top tape bar in the middle of my application but when I am trying to scroll it just scrolling but I want Twitter type behaviour so when we Scroll it can get full screen width how to do